# Does the PID Controller (LOVE 16C-3) Need an External SSR?

Tags: voltage, relay, solid-state-relay, pid-controller

My [PID controller LOVE 16C-3](http://www.pvi.com/pdf%20files/Love%20Control%20I.pdf) has a output of "relay".

Do I connect the output of the PID controller to the inputs of an external SSR?

Or is the relay already built in into the PID controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relay output is SPST [rated](http://www.alliedelec.com/m/d/aa619a68a2116cc22338e41aa00b595f.pdf) at 5A:

[image]

You cannot use this output to directly control a typical DC-input SSR without an external DC power supply of some type. It's just a normally-open contact.

You should not switch anything like 5A with it either, unless you want it to last a very short time. Typically life at full rated current is only perhaps 100,000 operations, which might be weeks or months 24/7.

They should repeat the datasheet specs within the manual, but I imagine this is just some rebranded no-name Asian product anyway. I doubt Love makes this kind of control these days (they did, many years ago).

Answer (score 1):

It appears from the manual that the output is an SPST relay contact, but the rating of the contact is not stated.

I suggest you contact the manufacturer to cxonfirm the relay contact specifications, and to obtain output wiring recommendations..

Answer (score 1):

The controller data sheet indicates that there are three outputs. A voltage mode output, a current mode output and an on/off relay output via a SPST relay.

[image]

Comment: The 16C-3 is the relay output version, but I can't make sense of the relay specs - need the contact voltage and currrent ratings.